# Android abrir imagem pelo caminho

Tags: android, imagem, path

Podemos ver que existem diversos tutoriais em como salvar o caminho de uma imagem, sendo uma foto da câmera ou selecionando da galeria, até ai ok, mas como buscar novamente a imagem pelo caminho dela? Procurei em diversos tutoriais mas não consegui encontrar uma solução, alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: O que você tem até o momento? onde está salvo as fotos SDCARD ou memoria interna? e qual a versão que você utiliza do android?

Comment: Primeiramente é saber onde voce gravou esta imagem!  segue uam documentação a respeito: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1):

Basta uma vez você tenha o endereço da imagem, basta chamar um intent para abrir.

```
private void openFullImage( String uriString )
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse( uriString ), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Espero que resolva seu problema.